# MySQL Calculating the value (price) difference between rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for product price logs and I want to calculate the price difference between the first date and the last date. I have tried with the min and max function but it doesn't provide desired results.

```
select (min(price) - max(price)) as diff from price_logs GROUP BY product_id
```

[image]

**The output should like.**

[image]

Kindly suggest. Thanks

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Version 5.7 MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
Select product,
       Sum(case when rnd=1 then price else -price end) as diff
  From
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by product order by date) as rn,
       Row_number() over (partition by product order by date desc) as rnd
  From your_table t) t
Where 1 in (rnd, rn)
Group by product;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `first_value()`:

```
select distinct p.product_id,
       (first_value(price) over (partition by product_id order by date) - 
        first_value(price) over (partition by product_id order by date desc)
       ) as diff 
from price_logs ;
```

Note that MySQL does not support a "first" or "last" aggregation function.  `first_value()` is a window function which is why this uses `select distinct`.